# How to limit the cloned table rows to 4?

Tags: jquery

=== table html structure ===

```
<div id="table-container">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Table head text</td>
<td>Table head text</td>
<td>Table head text</td>
<td>Table head text</td>
<td>Table head text</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="row">
<td width="10%" data-group="group" data-id="table1-row1-col1" data-type="integer" class="cell-editable" title="Click to input data"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
<td width="10%" data-group="group" data-id="table1-row2-col1" data-type="integer" class="cell-editable" title="Click to input data"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
<td width="10%" data-group="group" data-id="table1-row3-col1" data-type="integer" class="cell-editable" title="Click to input data"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
<td width="10%" data-group="group" data-id="table1-row4-col1" data-type="integer" class="cell-editable" title="Click to input data"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
<td width="10%" data-group="group" data-id="table1-row4-col1" data-type="integer" class="cell-editable" title="Click to input data"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

=== jquery ===

```
$( '#addNewTable' ).click(function() {
var source = $( '#table-container' ),
            clone = source.clone( true );
clone.insertAfter( source )
                .find( 'tbody tr td' ).not( 'tbody tr td:first-child, tbody tr td.title' ).text('')
                .find( 'tr.expend_row input[type="hidden"]' ).siblings().remove();
});
```

- I want to clone the source table but to only 4 rows. Dynamically the source table rows will be added by 1 through a button. And when I clone it, the whole structure will be clone which I don't want to do only until 4 rows.

Comment: Count rows before adding new one. What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks @Regent, I got this table that has a default rows of 4 and a button that would add a row each time it is clicked. And outside I got another button which would clone the table but I only what to clone the row to only 4 disregarding the other rows which is added dynamically the add row button.

Comment: just you will try this--http://jsfiddle.net/cfmlprabhu/uw9xx36n/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nishan Senevirathna, its new to me the .eq() & .nextAll()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
clone.find("tr").eq(3).nextAll().remove();
```

or in your case change your code like this,

```
$( '#addNewTable' ).click(function() {
   var source = $( '#table-container' );
   clone = source.clone( true );
   clone.find("tr").eq(3).nextAll().remove();
   clone.insertAfter( source )
                .find( 'tbody tr td' ).not( 'tbody tr td:first-child, tbody tr td.title' ).text('')
                .find( 'tr.expend_row input[type="hidden"]' ).siblings().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td:eq(1)').clone();
$('td:eq(2)').clone();
$('td:eq(3)').clone();
$('td:eq(4)').clone();
```

you can clone td one by one first four rows by applying this step or you can also append it to other as;

```
$('td:eq(1)').appendTo('.your-class-name');
```